# How much should one choose the number of executors and cores on a spark-submit job?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a spark **structured streaming** job that does the following:

> > 1. Streams from S3 Folder a file containing json (many json lines... like 12million)

> > 2. Filters them to exclude a couple of million

> > 3. Call an external HTTP api with each json (using concurrency)

> > 4. Write the response data to a Kafka topic

My source S3 folder can have up to 48 or more files, therefore I am using the:

```
.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
```

My EMR cluster is: (1 Master + 2 Slave Nodes) (each is of type: m5.2xlarge)

Each equipped with 8 cores and 32GB of memory.

In my spark job, I want to know what these options should be?

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--executor-memory ??g \
--driver-memory ??g \
--executor-cores ?? \
--num-executors ?? \
--queue default \
--deploy-mode cluster \
....
```

I want to distribute the load equally because I've been playing around with it and it seems like the transactions per sec that I am seeing on the HTTP endpoint is up/down and I think is a direct result of my parameters. I don't want to take the WHOLE cluster too. Any ideas?

Graph shows transactions per min of the HTTP endpoint being called.

[image: The following shows my HTTP endpoint being hit. Requests per min]

Comment: give your cluster setup please

Comment: @maximeG - Sure. Where can I find this info? Happy to provide if you can just guide me. Btw, I'm using Amazon AWS EMR so it is a fully managed cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depend of your time requirements, others jobs...
firstly you should maybe try with full cluster.

1 master + 2 slave = 3.
cores = 3 * 8 = 24
memory = 3 * 32 = 96

recommended number of core : 5 , we will decrease to 4 to dont have core left.
--executor-cores 4

number of executor = 24/4 = 6 (1 master and 5 executors)
--num-executors 5

executor-memory/driver-memory : (6/96)- ~10% = 14g

final parameter :

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--executor-memory 14g \
--driver-memory 14g \
--executor-cores 4 \
--num-executors 5 \
--queue default \
--deploy-mode cluster \
....
```

you can easly remove some Go from driver to give it to executors..